Django Azure Web App receiving 'Bad Request (400)' when accessed via the custom domain but works with the Azure provide default domain
I am deploying a Django Azure Web App and have added a custom domain that I bought off GoDaddy to it. I have also bound an SSL certificate provided by Azure to it.
When I access the website via the default Azure domain, I'm able to access it, but from the custom domain the server returns a 400 Bad Request.
I've added to the list of CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS as well as ALLOWED_HOSTS list the default domain as well as the custom domain.
I have selected from the configuration on Azure Web App the option to redirect HTTP request to HTTPS.
I have also added the DNS records (A and TXT) in GoDaddy to point to the server's public IP.
May I have suggestions on things I could do to get it working? I am a novice at this and it's my first time setting up a website.
I tried the following HTTPS settings in the settings.py file but it hasn't worked out, and I'm not too sure if I'm approaching it right either, thought I'd give it a go.
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True  
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000  
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True


To know more info about the issue,enable debug logging.

@Harshitha I have debug logging but all I'm getting in the log stream is a 400 bad request.
2024-10-17T10:31:46.8049536Z <IP address> - - [17/Oct/2024:10:31:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 143 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:131.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/131.0"
Generally I get more but when trying to access the server via the custom domain this is all I'm getting.
